# Divs inside panel displaying inline

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my angular app I have a bootstrap 'panel-body' class that features the two divs below which each wrap components that are user input fields.  For some reason these divs are rendering inline as opposed to on separate lines.  Why is this happening and how do I get the divs/components to render on separate lines?

note:  if I take out the divs and just have the components be there with no div wrapper, I get the same result.

```
<div ng-if="$ctrl.editWorkout" class="panel-body">
 ...
  <div>
    <field-meal-plan-workout-duration
      form="$ctrl.form"
      input-name="time"
      value="$ctrl.workout.duration"
      on-update="$ctrl.workout.duration = value">
    </field-meal-plan-workout-duration>
 </div>
 <div>
   <field-meal-plan-workout-difficulty
      form="$ctrl.form"
      input-name="difficulty"
      value="$ctrl.workout.difficulty"
      on-update="$ctrl.workout.difficulty = value">
    </field-meal-plan-workout-difficulty>
 </div>
```

Comment: Use 'clear: both; display:block;' on each elements you wanted to be separated.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This solved it.  Do you have any idea why the divs are rendering inline?

Comment: You are welcome. Please upvote/accept my answer. :)

Comment: my bad, divs are displayed block by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use clear: both; display:block;

Answer (score 1):

- create class .clear{ clear: both;}
- Set display mode as display: block